# How can I preserve colour attributes when creating an NSAttributedString with RTF?

Tags: objective-c, rtf

I am initialising an NSAttributedString with RTF and it works, in that I can see the text and attributes like font, size and weight are preserved.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attributedRTFString = [NSMutableAttributedString.alloc initWithRTF:rtfContent documentAttributes:nil];
```

Some attributes, notably colour, are lost though.  If I look at the RTF code I can see that those attributes are there (for example)…

```
{\*\htmltag72 </p>}
{\*\htmltag64 <p class=MsoNormal>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag84 <b>}\htmlrtf {\b \htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag148 <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#5F5F5F'>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag156 </span>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag92 </b>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag148 <span style='color:#1F497D'>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag244 <o:p>}
{\*\htmltag252 </o:p>}
{\*\htmltag156 </span>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0
\htmlrtf \par
\htmlrtf0
```

And I can see the colours in the original document.

How should I be opening RTF to preserve the formatting fully?

Comment: Quick question: If you create a `NSAttributedString` with some colors, and then convert it into RTF "Content", what are the colors tags?  Also, that seems to be "htmlrt", not only "rtf", so that could be the reason on why there are differences?

Comment: Nope - opening that file in Text Edit doesn't show the colour either (fine in Word for Windows though, but not in Word for Mac).  I can see that this isn't a problem that's been solved before - I'm going to have to write my own RTF tool.

Comment: it seems to be indeed a strange encoding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxrtfex/c2e2d599-a558-46ee-b5e0-7ccea266cb47 there was also a ticket https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2014/Apr/msg00428.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  My own RTF library is coming on though - so hopefully I'll be able to sort this.